# Active Model Serializer object not returning all association records (has many: through relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, has-many-through, active-model-serializers

So I have User&Role models which is linked to UserRole model using has_many :through association. And im using a serializer for User. Note: The user has many roles. But i'm not able to get all the roles in the serializer for some reason. This is the query,

```
unless params['roles'].blank?
  render json: User.includes(:roles)
                    .references(:user_roles)
                    .where('roles.name IN (?)', params['roles'])
else
  render json: User.all
end
```

And in my User serializer I have

```
attributes :id, :name, :email, :roles

def roles
  object.roles.pluck(:name)
end
```

This thing is, I have a user with both "admin","author" roles. When I pass "admin" as params, Output json object just has `roles: ["admin"]` for that user. Upon debugging, for this object, `object.roles.count` is 2 BUT when I do `object.roles`, it shows only 1 record. What's happening?

When I do `User.find(object.id).roles.pluck(:name)`, this works. But this runs queries in the serializer loop..

The output response is perfectly fine for User.all withOUT params. (getting roles: ["author", "admin"]). The problem is when I pass a param. Perhaps something wrong with my query?

Comment: [`.pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) will always create a DB query. Thats just how it works. If you want to use the loaded records use `object.roles.map(&:name)`.

Comment: There is also the question of what the actual desired result is. Since `.includes` creates an outer join the result will include users that don't have any matches in the join table (users with none of the roles). If you want to filter the user based on the roles you need to use `.joins` which creates a LEFT INNER JOIN or add a having clause to the query.

Comment: What actually happens when you use `.where` with `.includes` is that only the join table rows matching the predicate are loaded.

Comment: @max So I need all users that has "admin" role. or all users that has "admin" or "author" role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the where clause limits the loaded records you may need to use a subquery:

```
User.includes(:roles).where(
  id: User.joins(:roles).where(roles: { name: params[:roles] })
)
```

If you look at the SQL generated you can see that the where clause here only applies to the subquery - thus all the associated roles are loaded and not just the ones that match `WHERE "roles"."name" = $1`.

```
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_roles" ON "user_roles"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "user_roles"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."name" IN ($1, $2, $3)) LIMIT $4  [["name", "admin"], ["name", "foo"], ["name", "bar"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  UserRole Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "user_roles".* FROM "user_roles" WHERE "user_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

Also if you want to use the loaded records you need to use `map` not `pluck` as pluck by design creates a separate select query.

```
def roles
  object.roles.map(&:name)
end
```